# What is the scope of global PHP variables in a Drupal page?

Tags: php, drupal

Consider this PHP script:

```
<?php
  $a = "ok";
  function foo() {
    global $a; print "[$a]";
  }
  foo();
?>
```

It prints `[ok]` when run with a PHP interpreter as one would expect. But it prints just `[]` if run in a Drupal page. To make it work in Drupal I have to add another global specification before the variable declaration thus:

```
<?php
  global $a; // WHY IS THIS NEEDED IN DRUPAL?
  $a = "ok";
  function foo() {
    global $a; print "[$a]";
  }
  foo();
?>
```

Comment: Same server? Same version of PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Answer (score 1):

Likely because Drupal includes the file inside a function:

```
function render() {
    include 'my_script.php';
}
```

That makes `$a` local to the function, not `global`.